# No VGA Output please assist

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors, vga

I have been stuck on a problem for a couple of days now. A friend of mine's Laptop (Lenovo G560) was being used to connect to a projector daily - She is a teacher. She plugged a students phone into the laptop and the projector stopped displaying, She took the laptop to their IT guy who reinstalled windows 7. This did not fix the problem, I have tested various monitors and projectors all of them is detected and is shown under the devices all drivers are up to date but the external monitor/prjoector stays blank no output. What could cause this and how can I fix it? All the projectors works fine from my laptop and on their own.

Comment: So once you connect an external display and it's detected what happens when you go in to the screen resolution control panel within Windows and attempt to use that external display?

Comment: Hi, It gives me all the normal options like it is working but its not working. I can set it to primary or secondary adjust the resolution and everything but the display just stays black.

Answer (score 0):

On the Keyboard there are Function keys (Fn) and some key pads with an blue small icon on it.
Identify the key pad with external monitor / projector icon and use it together with the Fn key.

For example, press such a key-combination:
Fn + f8

or take a image of you keyboard and show it to us. Would help to solve this troubles.

Comment: I have tried all the Combo's it makes no difference. This model is Fn+F4

Comment: Is it possibile to move the mouse to the second screen?

Windows will not move the mouse out of an screen, if there is no other screen attached on the side where the mouse cursor went.

Comment: Yes I am able to move the mouse out of the screen and able to move the desktop to the second screen but the screen displays nothing, when I plug the same screen into another laptop the orange light on the screen turns green and works, on this laptop it just stays orange.

Comment: the same screen is an monitor or an projector?

Comment: It is a monitor, but it does the same thing on 2 different projectors I have tested. It's just easier to test with a monitor in daylight. The monitor works fine on my other laptop and desktop.

Comment: okay.
Can you connect the monitor and 
set the resolution of all screens (internal and external) to the lowest value?

Comment: Yes I have adjusted both to 800x600 still the same after I have applied the changes.

Comment: Sounds strange. Can you change the display connection cable to be sure that this cable is not broken?

Also try to restart the machine with the connected external monitor. While the machine is booting and before Windows is loaded I think that there should be some output on the screen. can you test this and provide the feedback here?

Comment: The Cable works fine on both my laptop and desktop, I have tested it. The laptop only has a VGA port no HDMI, I have restarted with and without the monitor plugged in made no difference. I have tested it while booting up and nothing happens, this is just very strange.